# How to keep the value of a variable constantly set without neither putting it in a cookie nor in a global variable?

Tags: php, variables

I am working on a PHP system where I need to have a couple of variables constantly set throughout all classes used. Data is mostly retrieved through ajax calls and MySQL queries.

The value of each variable will not change unless a specific link is clicked.

What is the best method to achieve this? I am a bit stuck because I can use neither global variables, nor a cookie.

Thanks in advance.

N.

Comment: cant you store it on the server?

Comment: store it in a db, retrieve on every page.

Comment: if the value doesn't change, what about a constant?

Comment: It can't be a constant because it will change, but only when the user switches from one part of the system to the other.
Being in the db would be a good idea, which I may resort to if need be, but I'd rather keep in the code, as I already have a lot of weight on the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Here is a simple example of using session:

```
 session_start();
 // Use $HTTP_SESSION_VARS with PHP 4.0.6 or less
 if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
    $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
 } else {
    $_SESSION['count']++;
 }
```

Some html later on ...

```
 <p>
Hello visitor, you have seen this page <?php echo $_SESSION['count']; ?> times.
</p>

<p>
To continue, <a href="nextpage.php?<?php echo htmlspecialchars(SID); ?>">click
here</a>.
</p>
```

Comment: Note that PHP sessions also use cookies unless otherwise specified, so there are other steps that need to be performed to achieve cookie-less sessions. stefgosselin has demonstrated one such necessary step: appending the session ID to every link.

Answer (score 0):

Store it in a super class then. So all subclasses derived from the super class can access this variable that is neither global nor a session variable.

```
<?
    class MySuperClass
    {
        protected myVariable;
    }

    class MySubClass extends MySuperClass
    {
        function bleh()
        {
            $this->myVariable = "yeah... neither global or cookie";
        }
    }
?>

// Or use $_SESSION instead of the above. $_SESSION['mynamespace']['my_variable'];
```

Comment: That could work under different circumstances, but not in this case. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

session_start();

echo $_SESSION['foo'];

$_SESSION['foo'] = $_REQUEST['foo'];

Answer (score -1):

You could use a registry. But think carefully whether you really need to do this and think about dependency injection. Try and make your code loosely coupled.

Comment: Yeah, that would definitely complicate things. session variable will be the way to go. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: A registry does not give you persistant data. The registry is rebuilt upon each request. And dependency injection does not have anything to do with the issue whatsoever, least not at this point.